# Using CSS custom properties (variables) with LESS functions

Tags: css, less, css-variables, tint

In my LESS file, I have this:

```
:root{
   --base-color: red;
}
```

In my project `--base-color` may change "on the fly" from a user input so every instance of **red** may become for example **green**.
The problem is I have some LESS functions for applying tint, shadow or saturations so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
.tint{
    color: tint(var(--base-color), 80%);
}
```

But I receive this error:

> Error: error evaluating function `tint`: color2.toHSL is not a
>   function

Obviously I can't store `--base-color` in a less variables because I would lose the instance of the variable, so `color: tint(@base-color, 80%)` is not an acceptable answer.

Is there a way to keep the instance of `--base-color` in my css minified field?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use a css variable in a less' color operation function. Less is transpiled before your color value even exists. You'd better choose a way: either use CSS4 or a CSS preprocessor like Sass.